# Android changing the color of switch states

Tags: android, android-widget, android-switch

I looked and many of the answers were deprecated for the older version.  I was wonder which attribute changes the color of a SwitchCompat widget.  I am looking to change both the on and off state colors when on I would like white while off would be another color

Answer (score 0):

You can use a program to do this. i don't think any attribute in switch xml could help you.
but maybe this could help you:

```
switchCompat.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
        if (b==true){
            //when Switch is On
            finalSwitchCompat.setTrackTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.GRAY));
            finalSwitchCompat.setThumbTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.GRAY));
        }
        else {
            finalSwitchCompat.setTrackTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.WHITE));
            finalSwitchCompat.setThumbTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.WHITE));
        }
    }
});
```